# xcode - callback with UIButton Event

Tags: xcode, events, callback, uibutton

I have an error says "EXEC_BAD_ACCESS". I want to run a callback after UIButton is clicked.

Here is my code:

***Dialog.m***

```
     - (void)showDialogInParentView: (UIView *)parentView
                          withText:(NSString *)text
                       leftBtnText:(NSString *)t1
                      rightBtnText:(NSString *)t2
                           handler:(void(^)(int))handler {

        vHandler = [handler copy];

        // INIT A CONTROL BUTTON WITH SELECTOR(EVENT) //
        _rightBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        _rightBtn.frame = CGRectMake((self.altView.frame.size.width / 2), 1.0, (self.altView.frame.size.width / 2), self.altView.frame.size.height);
        _rightBtn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [_rightBtn setTitle:@"Bla Bla" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [_rightBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(button_Click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // DO SOMETHINGS HERE //

}

- (void)button_Click: (UIButton *)sender {
    // CALLBACK HERE  WHEN CLICK THE BUTTON //
    vHandler(1);
}
```

Here is my code that calls:

***Foo.m***

```
-(void)showDialog {
    Dialog *d = [[Dialog alloc] init];
    [d showDialogInParentView:self.view
                                  withText:@"bla"
                               leftBtnText:@"bla bla"
                              rightBtnText:@"bla bla bla"
                                   handler:^(int res) {
                                       // DO SOMETHINGS //
                                   }];
}
```

Code works fine when I run the vHandler in ***- (void)showDialogInParentView: (UIView *)parentView
                              withText:(NSString *)text
                           leftBtnText:(NSString *)t1
                          rightBtnText:(NSString *)t2
                               handler:(void(^)(int))handle*** method. But I want to run vHandler when UIButton is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem myself. The problem is 'vHandler' is always null after init Dialog Class. So I used static variable then it has solved.

***Dialog.h***

```
+ (void)showDialogInParentView: (UIView *)parentView withText:(NSString *)text
                   leftBtnText:(NSString *)t1
                  rightBtnText:(NSString *)t2
                       handler:(void(^)(int))handler;
```

***Foo.m***

```
  static vHandler _handler;
```